# After oil change no oil in car but radiator overflow all oil

Tags: engine, oil, radiator

Just took 2013 Subaru Outback in for an oil change.  Drove home about 15 miles and have NO oil in the engine. The dipstick is dry and sticky. For some reason checked the radiator overflow and the oil is thick as thiefs with no appearance of water.  There appears to be no dripping. I think they put the oil in the radiator and not the engine.  Have had no engine issues before.

Comment: This sounds real bad.  Sorry this happened.  Unfortunately, you post doesn't ask a question.  Can you edit your post to ask a question?

Comment: I only see a court case here. In the future go to reputable workshops or the OEM Dealership. Avoid going to cheap places where you will save meager amount and spend half the cars value for your cheap savings plan.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be the first victim of an incompetent oil change shop.

Unfortunately, I fear your engine may be severely damaged due to driving, even a short distance, without oil in it.

Document everything!  You may need it if this mess ends up in a lawsuit.